# how to do loop over the tickers and save result on the dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I’m not so sure how to do the last part which is the dictionary part and ticker part, and also
On
“”file = open("/home/ubuntu/environment/hw5/" + tickers + “.txt”)””"
This line keep showing

TypeError: must be str, not list

Any suggestion on how to fix those or make the code works ?

Here’s my code

```
import json


def meanReversionStrategy(prices):
    
    total_profit = 0
    first_buy = None
    buy = 0
    for i in range(len(prices)):  
        
        
        if i >= 5: 
            current_price = prices[i]  
            moving_average = (prices[i-1] + prices[i-2] + prices[i-3] + prices[i-4] +prices[i-5]) / 5
        
            if current_price < moving_average * 0.95 and buy == 0:
                buy = current_price
                print("buy at:  ",round (current_price,2))  
                if first_buy is None:
                    first_buy = buy
                                
    
            elif current_price > moving_average * 1.05 and buy != 0:    
                
                print("sell at: ", round(current_price,2))
                print("trade profit:  ", round(current_price - buy,2))
                total_profit = current_price - buy
                buy = 0
            
            
    final_profit_percentage = ( total_profit / first_buy ) * 100 
    print("First buy: " ,  round(first_buy,2))
    print("Total profit: " , round(total_profit, 2))
    print("Percentage return: ", round(final_profit_percentage, 2),"%")  

def simpleMovingAverageStrategy(prices):
    i = 0
    buy = 0
    total_profit = 0
    first_buy = 0
    for p in prices:
        if i >= 5: 
            moving_average = (prices[i-1] + prices[i-2] + prices[i-3] + prices[i-4] + 
    prices[i-5]) / 5
            
            #simple moving average logic, not mean
            if p > moving_average and buy == 0: #buy
                print("buying at: ", p)
                buy = p
                if first_buy == 0:
                    first_buy = p
            elif p < moving_average and buy != 0: #sell
                print("selling at: ", p)
                print("trade profit: ", p - buy)
                total_profit += p - buy
                buy = 0
        i += 1
        
    final_percentage = (total_profit / first_buy) * 100
    print("first buy: ", first_buy)
    print("total profit: ", total_profit)
    print("final percentage: ", final_percentage, "%")
    
    return total_profit, final_percentage
        
        
tickers = ["AAPL1" , "ADBE" , "BA", "CMCSA", "CSCO", "CVS", "GOOG", "TLSYY","TM"]

file = open("/home/ubuntu/environment/hw5/" + tickers + ".txt")
lines = file.readlines()
# print(lines)
prices = []
for line in lines:
    prices.append(float(line))
    
    
profit, returns = simpleMovingAverageStrategy(prices)

results = {}
results["AAPL1_profit"] =profit
results["AAPL1_returns"] = returns

json.dump(results, open("/home/ubuntu/environment/hw5/results.json", "w") )
```

Coding Requirements

-Create a function called meanReversionStrategy which takes a list called “prices” as an argument.  The function runs a mean reversion strategy, and outputs to the console the buys and sells of the strategy (like you did in HW4).  The function returns the profit and final returns percentage.

-Create a function called simpleMovingAverageStrategy which takes a list called “prices” as an argument.  The function runs a Simple Moving Average strategy, and outputs to the console the buys and sells of the strategy.  The function returns the profit and final returns percentage.

-Create a function called saveResults which takes a dictionary as an argument.  Save the dictionary to a json file called “results.json”.

> > loop through the list of tickers

> > for ticker in tickers:

> > ```
> > -load prices from a file <ticker>.txt, and store them in the results dictionary with the
> > ```

> > ```
> > key “<ticker>_prices”
> > ```

> > ```
> > -call meanReversionStrategy(prices) and store the profit and returns in the results
> > ```

> > ```
> > dictionary with the keys “<ticker>_mr_profit” and “<ticker>_mr_returns”
> > ```

> > ```
> > -call simpleMovingAverageStrategy(prices) and store the profit and returns in the
> > ```

> > ```
> > results dictionary with the keys “<ticker>_sma_profit” and “<ticker>_sma_profit”
> > ```

> > ```
> > with the keys “ticker_mr_profit” and “ticker_mr_returns”
> > ```

> > call saveResults(results) and save the results dictionary to a file called results.json

Comment: Some advice on how to improve this question:
- Provide a meaningful title, which can be understood without reading the whole question
- Restrict your question to one problem at a time. Don't ask about solving your complete homework, it may offend people and is not in the sense of the question/answer sheme of stackoverflow. Related to that: Try to provide a minimal example and question.

Comment: got it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

As this is a homework question, I will not solve it for You, but here is my advice for You:

`tickers` is an array and as your homework description states, You must 'loop through the list of tickers' and `open` each of them. So how do You loop over `tickers`?

And reflect about the error. What do You think should be the result of `"/home/ubuntu/environment/hw5/" + tickers + ".txt"`?